# Issue with linked list implementation

Tags: python, linked-list

While implementing linked list in Python I faced a little conundrum. Here's my code

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = next_node

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next_node

    def set_next(self, new_next):
        self.next_node = new_next


class LinkedList(object):

    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head

    def insert(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = new_node


n = Node(1)
L = LinkedList()
print('data in node:', n.get_data())
print('next node:', n.get_next())
print('head:', L.head)

L.insert(n)
print('head after insertion:', L.head)
print('try to get data stored in head:', L.head.get_data())
```

The problem is illustrated by the last line: when I'm trying to get the data stored in head node, instead of that data I get `Node` object. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You insert a `Node`, then in the `insert` method you create a new `Node` from that `Node`. You want `L.insert(1)`, not `L.insert(Node(1))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here

```
   new_node = Node(data)
```

You're treating data as if it is a value while you're passing a `Node(1)` instead of simply `1`